# Appveyor caching of dependencies

Tags: appveyor

I'm using extra-cmake-modules and currently clone it on every build and install 
it on every build.

https://github.com/Snorenotify/Snorenotify/blob/master/appveyor.yml#L15

It would be great if I could cache the build as I don't need the latest version on every push.

But the documentation regarding caching doesn't offer a similar example. Is my scenario possible at all?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should only clone that repo if the directory does not exist:

```
- IF NOT EXIST %APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER%\work\extra-cmake-modules git clone git://anongit.kde.org/extra-cmake-modules.git
```

Then define cache entry in `appveyor.yml`:

```
cache:
- work\extra-cmake-modules -> appveyor.yml
```

which means "cache `work\extra-cmake-modules` folder unless `appveyor.yml` is changed".

Hope that helps.